# Getting $n\log_5(2) \sum_{k=1}^{\log_5(n)}\frac 1k$ from $\frac{n}{\log_5(5)}\sum_{j=0}^{\log_5(n) -1} \left(\frac{1}{\log_5(n) - j}\right) $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Very quick question please. If we have

$$\sum_{j=0}^{\log_5(n) -1} \left(\frac{n}{\log_5(\frac{n}{5^j}) - j}\right)$$

$$n\times\sum_{j=0}^{\log_5(n) -1} \left( \frac{1}{ \log_5(n)-j\log_5(5)} \right)$$

$$\frac{n}{\log_5(5)}\sum_{j=0}^{\log_5(n) -1} \left(\frac{1}{\log_5(n) - j}\right) \tag{1} \label{1}$$

$$n\log_5(2) \sum_{k=1}^{\log_5(n)}\frac 1k \tag{2} \label{2}$$

So, I am not sure if $n\log_5{2}$ is right in $(2)$, also, in $(1)$ we have $\log_5{n}$ always in the denominator inside sum, but in $(2)$ we don't have it. Can you please rewrite or add how we get \ref{2} from \ref{1}?

Comment: Can you show how you have gotten from $(1)$ to $(2)$?  Because these two are not equal - see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lqkceeukrg).

Comment: @DMcMor. That is why I posted it as you see, the one who wrote it I don't know how he/she wrote it :/ But this is the solution written in there.

Comment: Can you at least [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) as to where this came from?

Comment: @DMcMor. I will. Thanks.

Comment: $(2)=\log_52(1)$

Comment: @LalitTolani. Notice it's $log_5(2)$ in (2)  and $log_5(5)$ in (1). So I am not sure if you still think (2) = log2(1).

Comment: @Avra $\log_55 =1$

Comment: @LalitTolani. How (2) = (1) please. I am not sure what you mean, you can not simple multiply $log_5(2)$ without dividing on $log_5(2)$  otherwise, how you brought $log_5(2)$ please?

Comment: @DMcMor. Is it clearer now please?

Comment: @Avra I think there's some misunderstanding, What I am trying to say that equation 1 when multiplied by $\log_52$ gives equation 2